# Can I make a click-to-advance video player advance automatically by manipulating javascript in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a video player provided by a third party advance automatically.

I'm not sure quite what capabilities the console has to manipulate the behavior of web pages. The first thing I did was right click the player to see if there was a button you could press to turn auto-advance on, but there was no effect on right clicking.

So I used Chrome's "developer tools" to open the console, and I found the following code:

[image: Javascript]

Okay, cool. So I don't see an "autoplay = false"-type line, but here's another idea: change "player.allowRightClick = false" to "true." Then right click and see if the option comes up.

Unfortunately, nothing changed when I edited it.

So I have 2 questions.

1: am I entirely deluded that you can even attempt to modify code in the console this way?

2: Can I modify this player to auto-advance?

2.5: What additional information to you need to answer that?